# how can I create GeoJson for folium Python

Tags: python-3.x, geojson, spatial, folium

can anyone help me with the following **GeoJSON**, I am trying to work on **folium Python Library**, trying to plot all the `**LineStrings**`, but I want it with the **seperate colors** through the **id_** so I gave the ids option in my geoJson, and i want to `fillcolor` with the **id** option this id has multiple coordinate points, and there are more than **81 unique ids** in it, which makes multiple **`linestring`**, and i want to seperate those **`linestrings with colors`**

My first question is:

1. is it possible to do such thing what I am trying to with folium Python
2. if Yes, please help with my GeoJson File to correct it

this image is what I want to do:
[image]

```
cords = list(zip(filteredData.lat.tolist(), filteredData.lon.tolist()))
id_= list (zip(filteredData.id.tolist())) 
subVoyage

line = {
    'type': 'Feature',
    'geometry': {
        'type': 'LineString',
        'coordinates': cords,
        'ids': id_
    },
    'properties':{
        "color": 'black',
        "stroke": "red",
        "stroke-opacity": 0.4,
        "stroke-width": 5,
        "fillcolor" : id_,

    }
}

m1 = folium.Map(location=[36.862317, -76.3151], zoom_start=6)

folium.GeoJson(data, style_function=lambda x: {
        'color' : x['properties']['color'],
        'weight' : x['properties']['stroke-width'],
        'opacity': 1,
        'fillColor' : x['properties']['fillcolor'],
        }).add_to(m1)
m1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible as I've done a demo for your case in a notebook (see below code). Your issue seems to be related to the structure of your GeoJSON.

```
import folium

lines = {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"color": "#0000ff", "stroke-width": 1},"geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[-1.64794921875,46.46813299215554],[-0.94482421875,47.724544549099676],[-0.263671875,47.97521412341618]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"color": "#00ff00", "stroke-width": 1},"geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[-0.263671875,47.97521412341618],[1.58203125,48.67645370777654],[1.8896484375,48.32703913063476],[2.3291015625,48.37084770238366]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"color": "#ff0000", "stroke-width": 1},"geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[2.3291015625,48.37084770238366],[2.548828125,48.60385760823255],[3.01025390625,48.66194284607006],[3.251953125,48.42920055556841],[3.5815429687499996,48.531157010976706],[3.779296875,48.32703913063476]]}}]}


m1 = folium.Map(location=[45, 1], zoom_start=6)

style_function = lambda x: {
    'color' : x['properties']['color'],
    'weight' : x['properties']['stroke-width']
}

folium.GeoJson(lines, style_function=style_function).add_to(m1)

m1
```

You can see the result illustrated (Centered on France due to the GeoJSON I've used)

[image: Folium]

Comment: Thank you so much this is so much useful information for me, and this is really awesome, I have one more question how can I pass array of different colors generated dynamically with unique ids, and if that Id is matched with the co-ordinates array, then that line gets the color, is it possible?

Comment: Not sure I understand. From my viewpoint, the only action needed for what you wish is simply to dynamically generate GeoJSON. It's about looping in Python using your coords, your ids and their associated colors.

Comment: Thank you, I got your point.. and thanks, its really helpful post for me..